# Linq query not working on XML string

Tags: xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

i have a web service which returns xml data as string. i am trying to apply linq on xml string which is retunred by the service.

Lets say the xml stirng is some thing like.

```
string str = "<root xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/Count.xsd\"> <child> <subchild1>1</subchild1><subchild2>1</subchild2><subchild3>1</subchild3></child></root>";
```

Below is the c# code i am using.

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);  
 var item =  xdoc.Element("root").Element("child").Element("subchild1");
```

but the above query is always returning null.

can any one correct me what is wrong in above peace of code.

Comment: That code looks fine... Are you sure you are actually getting `null`?  Is that the exact XML you actually have?

Comment: i am gettin xmlns part of root. updated the main question.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
XNamespace xnp = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
  var item = xdoc.Element(xnp  + "root").Element(xnp  + "child").Element(xnp  + "subchild1").Value;
```